# Fetching JSON data: Syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, vue.js

I installed this [Drag and Drop](https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/draggable-example) plugin and tried to fetch my data from a local JSON file, however, I endeavoured an error: "Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON!" The JSON code I am using is down below.

```
    {"games":[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "name":"F5",
        "link":"someLink",
        "price":"50$"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "name":"BnS",
        "link":"someLink",
        "price":"35$"
    },
    {
        "id":"3",
        "name":"WoW",
        "link":"someLink",
        "price":"55$"
    },
]}
```

Where is the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try use this to validate your json [link](https://jsonlint.com/). Your json return error

Comment: remove the last comma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. You can try this one:

```
{
    "games": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "F5",
            "link": "someLink",
            "price": "50$"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "BnS",
            "link": "someLink",
            "price": "35$"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "WoW",
            "link": "someLink",
            "price": "55$"
        }
    ]
}
```

[Here's a useful tool for validating JSON](https://jsonlint.com/), which I just utilised to fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma after close brace after last object